# I can not select users that have departments in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

```
$users = User::with('departments')
->whereHas('departments', function ($q) use ($departments) {
  return $q->whereIn('department_id', $departments);
})->whereNotNull('users.email')
->get();
```

public function users(){return $this->morphedByMany(User::class, 'departmentable');}

```
in department model 
and
```

public function departments(){return $this->morphToMany(Department::class, 'departmentable');
}

```
in user model
```

Comment: What does `$departments` contain? Is it an array of department IDs? Or a `Collection` of `Department` models? Are you getting any kind of error?

Comment: that is array (4,8) for example

Comment: i have departmentables  too its morphTomany relation table

Comment: Ah, that might have something to do with it; post the function `public function departments()` inside of your `User.php` Model, and your `Department.php` Model. (Note: use the "Edit" button below the question; do not post as a comment)

Comment: sorry about that but i have departments function in user.php model

Comment: Let me rephrase; edit the question to include the contents of `public function departments()` from your `User.php` model, and the contents of your `Department.php` model.

Answer (score 0):

in your whereIn statement you use department_id column in departments table, are you sure of this, isn't just 'id' ('departments.id')?

```
  $users = User::with('departments')
->whereHas('departments', function ($q) use ($departments) {
  return $q->whereIn('departments.id', $departments);
})->whereNotNull('users.email')
->get();
```